# "web/session/authenticate" API endpoint returns an error instead of session_info in ODOO V16

Tags: odoo, odoo-16

I am using odoo V16. When I send a POST request to *web/session/authenticate* endpoint with the correct user credentials in the body like this:

```
{
    "params": {
        "db":<DB>,
        "login": <LOGIN>,
        "password": <PASSWORD>
    }
}
```

I get a bad response with the error message *"'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user'"*.
The expected behavior is a JSON response with session info like:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": null,
    "result": {...}
}
```

I'm not sure if it is a bug in the new odoo version or I'm doing something wrong. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

**Full error response**:

> {
> "jsonrpc": "2.0",
> "id": null,
> "error": {
> "code": 200,
> "message": "Odoo Server Error",
> "data": {
> "name": "builtins.AttributeError",
> "debug": "Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/odoo-16/odoo/http.py", line 1963, in **call**
> response = request._serve_nodb()
> File "/odoo-16/odoo/http.py", line 1516, in _serve_nodb
> response = self.dispatcher.dispatch(rule.endpoint, args)
> File "/odoo-16/odoo/http.py", line 1775, in dispatch
> result = endpoint(**self.request.params)
> File "/odoo-16/odoo/http.py", line 673, in route_wrapper
> result = endpoint(self, *args, **params_ok)
> File "/odoo-16/addons/web/controllers/session.py", line 52, in authenticate
> print('session_info', env['ir.http'].session_info())
> File "/odoo-16/addons/web_tour/models/ir_http.py", line 12, in session_info
> result = super().session_info()
> File "/odoo-16/addons/web/models/ir_http.py", line 68, in session_info
> user = request.env.user
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user'
> ",
> "message": "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user'",
> "arguments": [
> "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user'"
> ],
> "context": {}
> }
> }
> }

Comment: Yes, I am facing the same problem. Please any advice ??!!

Comment: @MohamadOsama Unfortunately this is a bug in odoo v16. I opened an issue on github [link](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/104587). 
Meanwhile I'm just using odoo v15 untill the new version is more stable. I don't recommend upgrading to odoo v16 in prod unless you know what you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem, and I found a workaround.

### **Problem**

The problem happen when you call the Odoo API for authentication `web/session/authenticate`.

We usually send the login data like this in `POST` request to the server

```
{"params":{"db":"odoo16","login":"admin","password":"***"}}
```

I got the error saying:

```
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/mail/models/ir_http.py", line 17, in session_info
     user = request.env.user
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user'
```

## Solution

This problem Happen when you has *`many databases`* in the server, so the request handler fail in fetching the `user` from `env` variable.

[image: Server has many databases]

But if you update your `odoo.conf` and added a `dbfilter = odoo16`, and restart the server. you will have only one database like this:

[image: One Database only]

Then if you call the API you will get the **CORRECT** response and **`works fine`** with you,

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": null,
    "result": {
        "uid": 2,
        "is_system": true,
        "is_admin": true,
        "user_context": {
            "lang": "en_US",
            "tz": "Africa/Cairo",
            "uid": 2
        },
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

Hope this help you fixing your issue till Odoo fix there bug.

Comment: You rock! yes indeed I had multiple databases running by the same odoo instance. I just want to add that explicitly defining `db_name = <DATABASE_NAME>` in config file fixes the issue as well